# Get data from remote push notification (ios, android)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

How I can get some data from push notification to my app? for example from my app I send some data with push notification. when my friend get that push notification he must tap on it and my app will automatically open and app must get that data from push. Is any way to do that?

Comment: When you tap on `Notification` you should navigate in some activity and download data. It's easy.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28958795/4033690

Comment: in that solution he just open the app by pressing on push and app update data from web service. I want send data from my Push to the App, for example I can send location data with push, and when friend pressed the push, the map opens in my app with that location parameters

Comment: I think what you're looking for is GCM - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/.